# How to create a Jar file with execution options?

Tags: java, linux, command-line, jar, executable-jar

How can I create a jar file with execution options, for example, the idea is execute the command:

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar -M someFile.txt
```

or

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar -cp someFile.txt
```

So the -M option defines a particular method to process the file someFile.txt and with -cp defines another behavior for the code.

With this in mine, how can I get this result from my code, is there something I need to write in the Main class, or how can I define such behavior?

Comment: Have you thought about using the `args` in `public static void main(String[] args)` for that?

Comment: For that case, I should define two arguments for the code, one for the function I need to choose `cp` or `M` and the input file, and catch them using an if statement on the main class?

Comment: Yes, exactly... That should be the choice in your case, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably need to check the Apache Commons-CLI, it allows you to do the things you describe above, also I give an example how it works, it give the way to specify a message   for the usage of the arguments:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/introduction.html

```
 Options options = new Options();

    options.addOption( "M", false,"Merge files request.")
            .addOption("CP", false,"Copy files from file.");

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    try {

        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        if (!cmd.hasOption("M")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify an input file.");
        }
        // Do something

        if (!cmd.hasOption("CP")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify an input file.");
        }

       // Do something

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMEssage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*take a look at* [*this example*](https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Compiling_and_Running_with_Arguments).

basically the `args`
in your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

args = the **arg**ument**s** you put after `java -jar MyJar.jar`
      for example `-cp someFile.txt`
      as a String[]: `{"-cp", "someFile.txt"}`